# Why do the basis functions of a Fourier series have only integer multiples of the frequency?

Tags: vector-spaces, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, schauder-basis

We are learning about Fourier series expansion, and we were given this equation:
$$x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n e^{j2\pi n f_0 t}$$
where $f_0$ is the frequency of the function $x(t)$

I only know a little linear algebra, but I understand that this equation (sort of...?) says the set of complex exponentials:
$$\{ e^{j2\pi n f_0 t}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
forms an orthonormal basis of the vector space in which $x(t)$ resides. And I get that this means that we can represent $x(t)$ as a linear combination of the basis functions of its overarching vector space.

But I am very confused as to why complex exponentials with only integer multiples, $2\pi n f_0 t$, of the function's frequency suffice to form a basis for this space--why not the set of complex exponentials of ALL frequencies, i.e. $n\in\mathbb{R}$?

Said another way--Why does it **only** take the set of all complex exponentials with integer multiples of $f_0$ to express the $x(t)$?.

Another, related question--what exactly is the vector space that $x(t)$ is a member of? Is it tied directly to $f_0$?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: $f_0$ is the frequency, not the period.  The period is $1/f_0$.

Comment: whoops, forgot to fix that

Comment: If $f$ is periodic, then we would have integers. For non-periodic $f$ we have $n\in\mathbb R$. That's evident from the fact that $e^{i\omega}$ is periodic

Comment: The vector space in which $x$ resides is the space of functions with period $1/f_0$ (i.e. frequency $f_0$).  Note that adding any such functions together produces another.

Answer (score 1):

You only need integer multiples of a single base frequency because $x(t)$ is assumed to be periodic with period $\frac1{f_0}.$

If $x(t)$ weren't assumed to be periodic, this wouldn't work (and you'd need to try to move to something like the Fourier integral).

Comment: Right, but why does the periodicity of $x(t)$ allow you to ignore all the other frequencies?

Comment: @BenGranger If $f(x)+g(x)=h(x)$ and $f$ and $g$ are both periodic with periods $T_f$ and $T_g$, under what condition $h(x)$ would be periodic? You can show that $h$ is periodic _if and only if_ $\frac{T_f}{T_g}\in\mathbb Q$

Comment: Ohhh, so if we know that $x(t)$ is periodic, then we are **guaranteed** that there is some linear combination of other periodic functions that will equal $x(t)$, and the Fourier series expansion is one such linear combination of periodic functions--is that correct?

Comment: @BenGranger Not the exact wording I would use, but correct

Comment: Awesome, but then why the integer multiples? Does it ensure that the resulting sum has the frequency $f_0$?

Comment: @BenGranger "Guaranteed" is too strong a word in general, since a function $f$ needs to satisfy certain conditions for its Fourier series to converge to $f$ (at, say, its points of continuity).  Look up "Dirichlet conditions" for more information on this.

Comment: Based on those, I suppose I mean 'guaranteed for periodic functions satisfying those conditions'

Comment: "... why the integer multiples?" If you think of it in terms of periods, then a function of period $p/n$ (where $n$ is an integer) is also a function of period $p,$ so you're adding up a bunch of functions of period $p$ -- which makes sense because you want the sum to have period $p.$

Comment: @MitchellSpector very clear, thank you, that makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

lets assume x(t) is some periodic function that repeats after $T_0$, then

x(t) = x(t+ n$T_0$)

Lets introduce new function with different time period

g(t) = g(t + n (p/q$T_0$))  $\qquad$   { p and q are integers and q > 1 }

p/q is some fraction of $T_0$, then its assume g(t) contributes its part along linear combination of complex exponential basis functions in x(t)'s

x(t) = $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k e^{j 2\pi k f_0 t}  +  g(t)$

x(t + m$T_0$) =  $\quad$above summation remains as it is  $\quad$ +  $\quad$g(t + m$T_0$),

g(t + m$T_0$) will not always give the same value unless $\rightarrow$ m = multiples of q

It is guarantee that g(t) gives same value after every m=k(q$T_0$), then to synchronise with

$\rightarrow \quad$  x(t)'s $T_0 \quad$ and $\quad$ g(t)'s q$T_0$

q had to be 1, g(t)'s time period had to be at least $T_0$

And further $T_0$ can be made generalised to expression n$T_0$ {n $\in$ I}

So we can expand g(t) into its Fourier series and it will smoothly and beautifully merge into the above summation series.

Thus x(t) cannot be made out of other frequencies else its Time period would not be the same and signal would be something else.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos : ) Thanks : )